# How to use Arabic font in VB6.0

Tags: textbox, arabic

I have a textbox in my project. I set the font to an arabic font and when i run my project and type something in that text box it shows in English. Is there any way to display it in Arabic?

Answer (score 0):

well i haven't worked a lot in VB6.0, you may use the Richtextbox control.

Comment: try this: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?724625-Arabic-Fonts-in-Textbox&p=4434615